# JMeter: Unexpected behavior with identical values for return URL and client ID after a successful test

Tags: jmeter, openid-connect, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-logging

> JMeter: Unexpected behavior with identical values for return URL and client ID after a successful test

I'm currently working with JMeter for performance testing of an application that implements the OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol for authentication. During the test execution, I noticed an unexpected behavior where, upon successful completion of the test, both the return URL and client ID are receiving the same values(in Service bus Queue). This behavior is not aligned with the expected behavior defined in the OIDC specifications.

Here are some details about my setup:

- I have a JMeter test plan that simulates user interactions with a web application that involves      OIDC authentication.
- The test plan includes HTTP requests, timers, and assertions to validate the application's behavior.
- The return URL and client ID are parameters used in the OIDC flow.
- I've verified that the test passes successfully, but the received values for the return URL and client ID are identical(in Service bus Queue).

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions regarding the potential causes of this unexpected behavior in JMeter with OIDC information.

What could be the reasons behind both the return URL and client ID receiving the same values after a successful test?

If there are any recommended troubleshooting steps or best practices specific to JMeter and OIDC testing, please share them as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all run the same scenario using the real browser and see if the problem is there. If yes - it's your application defect.
2. If the issue is reproducible in JMeter and isn't in the real browser your test plan is not correct. Make sure that [JMeter is properly configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and it sends the same requests as the real browser does.

   Use a sniffer tools like Fiddler or Wireshark to compare requests originating from JMeter and from the real browser and compare them. The requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))
3. JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful and it might be the case that JMeter is not doing what it is supposed to be doing. Inspect requests and responses using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and maybe add [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to ensure that you're receiving the anticipated responses

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I tried the above steps but it is not helping. I'm still facing the same behavior